# Infinite Loop when deploying to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I would like to deploy a Docker image containing `Keycloak` to `Elastic Beanstalk`.

To do so I created a `Dockerfile` like this.

```
FROM bitnami/keycloak:19.0.2

EXPOSE 5000
```

This deploys successfully when running `eb deploy`.

I would now like to compile some Java code and copy it into the `Keycloak` image.

```
FROM gradle:7.5.0-jdk11-alpine AS spi
COPY --chown=gradle:gradle ./spi /spi
WORKDIR /spi
RUN gradle build --no-daemon

FROM bitnami/keycloak:19

COPY --from=spi /spi/build/libs/* /opt/keycloak/providers/keycloak-spi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

EXPOSE 5000
```

This builds successfully using `docker build --no-cache -t keycloak .` and can be run using `docker run` locally.

If I try deploying this to `Elastic Beanstalk` it deploys indefinitely. I can't cancel the deployment and have to force it to stop by setting the Auto Scaling Group capacity to `0`.

```
----------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-hooks.log
----------------------------------------


----------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/access.log
----------------------------------------
172.31.15.133 - - [29/Sep/2022:17:05:19 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.35.107 - - [29/Sep/2022:17:05:19 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.15.133 - - [29/Sep/2022:17:05:32 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "86.11.104.152"
172.31.15.133 - - [29/Sep/2022:17:05:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.35.107 - - [29/Sep/2022:17:05:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"


----------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/error.log
----------------------------------------
2022/09/29 17:05:19 [error] 4202#4202: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.15.133, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.2:5000/", host: "172.31.7.44"
2022/09/29 17:05:19 [error] 4202#4202: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.35.107, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.2:5000/", host: "172.31.7.44"
2022/09/29 17:05:32 [error] 4202#4202: *5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.15.133, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.2:5000/", host: "keycloak-dev.eu-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2022/09/29 17:05:34 [error] 4202#4202: *7 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.15.133, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.2:5000/", host: "172.31.7.44"
2022/09/29 17:05:34 [error] 4202#4202: *9 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.35.107, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.2:5000/", host: "172.31.7.44"


----------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/eb-48320d59a48b-stdouterr.log
----------------------------------------
[38;5;6mkeycloak [38;5;5m17:05:06.31 [0m
[38;5;6mkeycloak [38;5;5m17:05:06.32 [0m[1mWelcome to the Bitnami keycloak container[0m
[38;5;6mkeycloak [38;5;5m17:05:06.32 [0mSubscribe to project updates by watching [1mhttps://github.com/bitnami/containers[0m
[38;5;6mkeycloak [38;5;5m17:05:06.32 [0mSubmit issues and feature requests at [1mhttps://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues[0m
[38;5;6mkeycloak [38;5;5m17:05:06.32 [0m
[38;5;6mkeycloak [38;5;5m17:05:06.32 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> ** Starting keycloak setup **
[38;5;6mkeycloak [38;5;5m17:05:06.33 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> Validating settings in KEYCLOAK_* env vars...
[38;5;6mkeycloak [38;5;5m17:05:06.35 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> Trying to connect to PostgreSQL server awseb-e-2mwnvjecwe-stack-awsebrdsdatabase-qb51rlaqbaxv.czdgrvr4inhi.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com...
[38;5;6mkeycloak [38;5;5m17:05:06.38 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> Found PostgreSQL server listening at awseb-e-2mwnvjecwe-stack-awsebrdsdatabase-qb51rlaqbaxv.czdgrvr4inhi.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432
[38;5;6mkeycloak [38;5;5m17:05:06.38 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> Configuring database settings
[38;5;6mkeycloak [38;5;5m17:05:06.41 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> Enabling statistics
[38;5;6mkeycloak [38;5;5m17:05:06.41 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> Configuring http settings
[38;5;6mkeycloak [38;5;5m17:05:06.42 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> Configuring hostname settings
[38;5;6mkeycloak [38;5;5m17:05:06.43 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> Configuring cache count
[38;5;6mkeycloak [38;5;5m17:05:06.43 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> Configuring log level
[38;5;6mkeycloak [38;5;5m17:05:06.44 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> Configuring proxy
[38;5;6mkeycloak [38;5;5m17:05:06.45 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> ** keycloak setup finished! **

[38;5;6mkeycloak [38;5;5m17:05:06.46 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> ** Starting keycloak **
Updating the configuration and installing your custom providers, if any. Please wait.
2022-09-29 17:05:19,703 WARN  [org.keycloak.services] (build-43) KC-SERVICES0047: metrics (org.jboss.aerogear.keycloak.metrics.MetricsEndpointFactory) is implementing the internal SPI realm-restapi-extension. This SPI is internal and may change without notice
2022-09-29 17:05:21,233 WARN  [org.keycloak.services] (build-43) KC-SERVICES0047: metrics-listener (org.jboss.aerogear.keycloak.metrics.MetricsEventListenerFactory) is implementing the internal SPI eventsListener. This SPI is internal and may change without notice
2022-09-29 17:05:32,212 INFO  [io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor] (main) Quarkus augmentation completed in 21445ms
2022-09-29 17:05:35,762 INFO  [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.hostname.DefaultHostnameProvider] (main) Hostname settings: Base URL: <unset>, Hostname: <request>, Strict HTTPS: false, Path: <request>, Strict BackChannel: false, Admin URL: <unset>, Admin: <request>, Port: -1, Proxied: true
2022-09-29 17:05:38,486 INFO  [org.keycloak.common.crypto.CryptoIntegration] (main) Detected crypto provider: org.keycloak.crypto.def.DefaultCryptoProvider


----------------------------------------
/var/log/docker-events.log
----------------------------------------
2022-09-29T17:05:03.177179628Z image pull bitnami/keycloak:19 (name=bitnami/keycloak, org.opencontainers.image.authors=https://bitnami.com/contact, org.opencontainers.image.description=Application packaged by Bitnami, org.opencontainers.image.ref.name=19.0.2-debian-11-r4, org.opencontainers.image.source=https://github.com/bitnami/containers/tree/main/bitnami/keycloak, org.opencontainers.image.title=keycloak, org.opencontainers.image.vendor=VMware, Inc., org.opencontainers.image.version=19.0.2)
2022-09-29T17:05:03.398516443Z container create edf1b48a9117e98a17c3c65139a2c3131ba40c31cc036faba9d7e541eb1308a4 (image=sha256:2a52f7074b400c46837253be0cd6719054373aa15c556a2505cfc4875c732191, name=crazy_keldysh, org.opencontainers.image.authors=https://bitnami.com/contact, org.opencontainers.image.description=Application packaged by Bitnami, org.opencontainers.image.ref.name=19.0.2-debian-11-r4, org.opencontainers.image.source=https://github.com/bitnami/containers/tree/main/bitnami/keycloak, org.opencontainers.image.title=keycloak, org.opencontainers.image.vendor=VMware, Inc., org.opencontainers.image.version=19.0.2)
2022-09-29T17:05:03.467499766Z container destroy edf1b48a9117e98a17c3c65139a2c3131ba40c31cc036faba9d7e541eb1308a4 (image=sha256:2a52f7074b400c46837253be0cd6719054373aa15c556a2505cfc4875c732191, name=crazy_keldysh, org.opencontainers.image.authors=https://bitnami.com/contact, org.opencontainers.image.description=Application packaged by Bitnami, org.opencontainers.image.ref.name=19.0.2-debian-11-r4, org.opencontainers.image.source=https://github.com/bitnami/containers/tree/main/bitnami/keycloak, org.opencontainers.image.title=keycloak, org.opencontainers.image.vendor=VMware, Inc., org.opencontainers.image.version=19.0.2)
2022-09-29T17:05:03.471362994Z image tag sha256:5d99cf30b3aec76495a2db5b6e5292125f31f29ddfe7aca21789abd2f13fc30c (name=aws_beanstalk/staging-app:latest, org.opencontainers.image.authors=https://bitnami.com/contact, org.opencontainers.image.description=Application packaged by Bitnami, org.opencontainers.image.ref.name=19.0.2-debian-11-r4, org.opencontainers.image.source=https://github.com/bitnami/containers/tree/main/bitnami/keycloak, org.opencontainers.image.title=keycloak, org.opencontainers.image.vendor=VMware, Inc., org.opencontainers.image.version=19.0.2)
2022-09-29T17:05:05.646632020Z container create 48320d59a48b027ab5d08531271a2cd0c4cafac5e80f322fa7fc98c0849ba5b4 (image=5d99cf30b3ae, name=cool_pasteur, org.opencontainers.image.authors=https://bitnami.com/contact, org.opencontainers.image.description=Application packaged by Bitnami, org.opencontainers.image.ref.name=19.0.2-debian-11-r4, org.opencontainers.image.source=https://github.com/bitnami/containers/tree/main/bitnami/keycloak, org.opencontainers.image.title=keycloak, org.opencontainers.image.vendor=VMware, Inc., org.opencontainers.image.version=19.0.2)
2022-09-29T17:05:05.718178496Z network connect b4145308580fd568a5789e6f5345557a657c66187a05059e0e1d0e7d0813bab6 (container=48320d59a48b027ab5d08531271a2cd0c4cafac5e80f322fa7fc98c0849ba5b4, name=bridge, type=bridge)
2022-09-29T17:05:06.289309003Z container start 48320d59a48b027ab5d08531271a2cd0c4cafac5e80f322fa7fc98c0849ba5b4 (image=5d99cf30b3ae, name=cool_pasteur, org.opencontainers.image.authors=https://bitnami.com/contact, org.opencontainers.image.description=Application packaged by Bitnami, org.opencontainers.image.ref.name=19.0.2-debian-11-r4, org.opencontainers.image.source=https://github.com/bitnami/containers/tree/main/bitnami/keycloak, org.opencontainers.image.title=keycloak, org.opencontainers.image.vendor=VMware, Inc., org.opencontainers.image.version=19.0.2)
2022-09-29T17:05:12.038251773Z image tag sha256:5d99cf30b3aec76495a2db5b6e5292125f31f29ddfe7aca21789abd2f13fc30c (name=aws_beanstalk/current-app:latest, org.opencontainers.image.authors=https://bitnami.com/contact, org.opencontainers.image.description=Application packaged by Bitnami, org.opencontainers.image.ref.name=19.0.2-debian-11-r4, org.opencontainers.image.source=https://github.com/bitnami/containers/tree/main/bitnami/keycloak, org.opencontainers.image.title=keycloak, org.opencontainers.image.vendor=VMware, Inc., org.opencontainers.image.version=19.0.2)
2022-09-29T17:05:12.101612937Z image untag sha256:5d99cf30b3aec76495a2db5b6e5292125f31f29ddfe7aca21789abd2f13fc30c (name=sha256:5d99cf30b3aec76495a2db5b6e5292125f31f29ddfe7aca21789abd2f13fc30c, org.opencontainers.image.authors=https://bitnami.com/contact, org.opencontainers.image.description=Application packaged by Bitnami, org.opencontainers.image.ref.name=19.0.2-debian-11-r4, org.opencontainers.image.source=https://github.com/bitnami/containers/tree/main/bitnami/keycloak, org.opencontainers.image.title=keycloak, org.opencontainers.image.vendor=VMware, Inc., org.opencontainers.image.version=19.0.2)
2022-09-29T17:05:13.916310158Z image tag sha256:5d99cf30b3aec76495a2db5b6e5292125f31f29ddfe7aca21789abd2f13fc30c (name=aws_beanstalk/current-app:latest, org.opencontainers.image.authors=https://bitnami.com/contact, org.opencontainers.image.description=Application packaged by Bitnami, org.opencontainers.image.ref.name=19.0.2-debian-11-r4, org.opencontainers.image.source=https://github.com/bitnami/containers/tree/main/bitnami/keycloak, org.opencontainers.image.title=keycloak, org.opencontainers.image.vendor=VMware, Inc., org.opencontainers.image.version=19.0.2)
2022-09-29T17:05:14.010857853Z image tag sha256:2a52f7074b400c46837253be0cd6719054373aa15c556a2505cfc4875c732191 (name=bitnami/keycloak:19, org.opencontainers.image.authors=https://bitnami.com/contact, org.opencontainers.image.description=Application packaged by Bitnami, org.opencontainers.image.ref.name=19.0.2-debian-11-r4, org.opencontainers.image.source=https://github.com/bitnami/containers/tree/main/bitnami/keycloak, org.opencontainers.image.title=keycloak, org.opencontainers.image.vendor=VMware, Inc., org.opencontainers.image.version=19.0.2)


----------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-docker-process.log
----------------------------------------
2022/09/29 17:05:12.516005 [INFO] Loading Manifest...
2022/09/29 17:05:12.553556 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-2:882618350644:stack/awseb-e-2mwnvjecwe-stack/e6e0d050-3f75-11ed-a0e9-0a1f03d7e8a8 -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region eu-west-2
2022/09/29 17:05:14.188072 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-2:882618350644:stack/awseb-e-2mwnvjecwe-stack/e6e0d050-3f75-11ed-a0e9-0a1f03d7e8a8 -r AWSEBBeanstalkMetadata --region eu-west-2
2022/09/29 17:05:15.706457 [INFO] Checking if docker is running...
2022/09/29 17:05:15.706480 [INFO] Fetch current app container id...
2022/09/29 17:05:15.706802 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker ps | grep 48320d59a48b
2022/09/29 17:05:15.851077 [INFO] 48320d59a48b   5d99cf30b3ae   "/opt/bitnami/scriptâ€¦"   10 seconds ago   Up 9 seconds   5000/tcp   cool_pasteur

2022/09/29 17:05:15.851106 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker wait  48320d59a48b


----------------------------------------
/var/log/docker
----------------------------------------
Sep 29 17:04:41 ip-172-31-7-44 docker: time="2022-09-29T17:04:41.522348910Z" level=info msg="Starting up"
Sep 29 17:04:41 ip-172-31-7-44 docker: time="2022-09-29T17:04:41.546445360Z" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
Sep 29 17:04:41 ip-172-31-7-44 docker: time="2022-09-29T17:04:41.546469970Z" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Sep 29 17:04:41 ip-172-31-7-44 docker: time="2022-09-29T17:04:41.546492925Z" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}" module=grpc
Sep 29 17:04:41 ip-172-31-7-44 docker: time="2022-09-29T17:04:41.546507007Z" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Sep 29 17:04:41 ip-172-31-7-44 docker: time="2022-09-29T17:04:41.585273534Z" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
Sep 29 17:04:41 ip-172-31-7-44 docker: time="2022-09-29T17:04:41.585318052Z" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Sep 29 17:04:41 ip-172-31-7-44 docker: time="2022-09-29T17:04:41.585339847Z" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}" module=grpc
Sep 29 17:04:41 ip-172-31-7-44 docker: time="2022-09-29T17:04:41.585350796Z" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Sep 29 17:04:41 ip-172-31-7-44 docker: time="2022-09-29T17:04:41.870138260Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Sep 29 17:04:42 ip-172-31-7-44 docker: time="2022-09-29T17:04:42.576967756Z" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
Sep 29 17:04:42 ip-172-31-7-44 docker: time="2022-09-29T17:04:42.737972210Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Sep 29 17:04:43 ip-172-31-7-44 docker: time="2022-09-29T17:04:43.044803469Z" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=a89b842 graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=20.10.17
Sep 29 17:04:43 ip-172-31-7-44 docker: time="2022-09-29T17:04:43.045249096Z" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Sep 29 17:04:43 ip-172-31-7-44 docker: time="2022-09-29T17:04:43.082693306Z" level=info msg="API listen on /run/docker.sock"
Sep 29 17:05:03 ip-172-31-7-44 docker: time="2022-09-29T17:05:03.459921076Z" level=info msg="Layer sha256:35c7205075f4f3bd7f9b0e488668782fa244a75cccb6a6ef6a3b14251b55236d cleaned up"


----------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-engine.log
----------------------------------------
2022/09/29 17:05:11.511727 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf nginx.service
2022/09/29 17:05:11.523154 [INFO] register process nginx
2022/09/29 17:05:11.523176 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf nginx.service
2022/09/29 17:05:11.537946 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl daemon-reload
2022/09/29 17:05:11.659032 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl reset-failed
2022/09/29 17:05:11.666538 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl enable nginx.service
2022/09/29 17:05:11.786233 [INFO] Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/nginx.service to /usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service.

2022/09/29 17:05:11.786293 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf nginx.service
2022/09/29 17:05:11.802086 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl restart nginx.service
2022/09/29 17:05:11.904366 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c service iptables save
2022/09/29 17:05:11.966054 [INFO] iptables: Saving firewall rules to /etc/sysconfig/iptables: [  OK  ]

2022/09/29 17:05:11.966069 [INFO] Traffic forward set-up completed.
2022/09/29 17:05:11.966074 [INFO] making STAGING app container current...
2022/09/29 17:05:11.966088 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker tag 5d99cf30b3ae aws_beanstalk/current-app
2022/09/29 17:05:12.041952 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker rmi aws_beanstalk/staging-app
2022/09/29 17:05:12.106692 [INFO] Untagged: aws_beanstalk/staging-app:latest

2022/09/29 17:05:12.106769 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf eb-docker.service
2022/09/29 17:05:12.118591 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl daemon-reload
2022/09/29 17:05:12.242722 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl reset-failed
2022/09/29 17:05:12.250703 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl enable eb-docker.service
2022/09/29 17:05:12.365666 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf eb-docker.service
2022/09/29 17:05:12.382129 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-active eb-docker.service
2022/09/29 17:05:12.390717 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl start eb-docker.service
2022/09/29 17:05:12.465476 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf eb-docker-log.service
2022/09/29 17:05:12.479384 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl daemon-reload
2022/09/29 17:05:12.620319 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl reset-failed
2022/09/29 17:05:12.638521 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl enable eb-docker-log.service
2022/09/29 17:05:12.787312 [INFO] Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/eb-docker.service.wants/eb-docker-log.service to /etc/systemd/system/eb-docker-log.service.

2022/09/29 17:05:12.787345 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf eb-docker-log.service
2022/09/29 17:05:12.803790 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-active eb-docker-log.service
2022/09/29 17:05:12.814626 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl start eb-docker-log.service
2022/09/29 17:05:12.939662 [INFO] docker container 48320d59a48b is running aws_beanstalk/current-app
2022/09/29 17:05:12.939681 [INFO] Executing instruction: Clean up Docker
2022/09/29 17:05:12.939710 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker ps -aq
2022/09/29 17:05:13.129931 [INFO] 48320d59a48b

2022/09/29 17:05:13.129970 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker images | sed 1d
2022/09/29 17:05:13.282274 [INFO] aws_beanstalk/current-app   latest    5d99cf30b3ae   10 seconds ago   622MB
bitnami/keycloak            19        2a52f7074b40   3 days ago       622MB

2022/09/29 17:05:13.282303 [INFO] save docker tag command: docker tag 5d99cf30b3ae aws_beanstalk/current-app:latest
2022/09/29 17:05:13.282309 [INFO] save docker tag command: docker tag 2a52f7074b40 bitnami/keycloak:19
2022/09/29 17:05:13.282321 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker rm `docker ps -aq`
2022/09/29 17:05:13.529450 [INFO] Error response from daemon: You cannot remove a running container 48320d59a48b027ab5d08531271a2cd0c4cafac5e80f322fa7fc98c0849ba5b4. Stop the container before attempting removal or force remove

2022/09/29 17:05:13.529511 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker rmi `docker images -aq`
2022/09/29 17:05:13.789049 [INFO] Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 5d99cf30b3ae (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container 48320d59a48b
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 2a52f7074b40 (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images

2022/09/29 17:05:13.789067 [INFO] restore docker image name with command: docker tag 5d99cf30b3ae aws_beanstalk/current-app:latest
2022/09/29 17:05:13.789078 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker tag 5d99cf30b3ae aws_beanstalk/current-app:latest
2022/09/29 17:05:13.918414 [INFO] restore docker image name with command: docker tag 2a52f7074b40 bitnami/keycloak:19
2022/09/29 17:05:13.918438 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker tag 2a52f7074b40 bitnami/keycloak:19
2022/09/29 17:05:14.013863 [INFO] Executing instruction: start X-Ray
2022/09/29 17:05:14.013880 [INFO] X-Ray is not enabled.
2022/09/29 17:05:14.013885 [INFO] Executing instruction: configureSqsd
2022/09/29 17:05:14.013891 [INFO] This is a web server environment instance, skip configure sqsd daemon ...
2022/09/29 17:05:14.013896 [INFO] Executing instruction: startSqsd
2022/09/29 17:05:14.013900 [INFO] This is a web server environment instance, skip start sqsd daemon ...
2022/09/29 17:05:14.013905 [INFO] Executing instruction: Track pids in healthd
2022/09/29 17:05:14.013910 [INFO] This is an enhanced health env...
2022/09/29 17:05:14.013939 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p ConsistsOf aws-eb.target | cut -d= -f2
2022/09/29 17:05:14.032650 [INFO] eb-docker.service healthd.service nginx.service eb-docker-events.service cfn-hup.service eb-docker-log.service docker.service

2022/09/29 17:05:14.032683 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p ConsistsOf eb-app.target | cut -d= -f2
2022/09/29 17:05:14.055602 [INFO] 

2022/09/29 17:05:14.057747 [INFO] Executing instruction: Configure Docker Container Logging
2022/09/29 17:05:14.066518 [INFO] Executing instruction: RunAppDeployPostDeployHooks
2022/09/29 17:05:14.066536 [INFO] Executing platform hooks in .platform/hooks/postdeploy/
2022/09/29 17:05:14.066560 [INFO] The dir .platform/hooks/postdeploy/ does not exist
2022/09/29 17:05:14.066564 [INFO] Finished running scripts in /var/app/current/.platform/hooks/postdeploy
2022/09/29 17:05:14.066572 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2022/09/29 17:05:14.068115 [INFO] Platform Engine finished execution on command: self-startup

2022/09/29 17:05:39.149172 [INFO] Starting...
2022/09/29 17:05:39.149959 [INFO] Starting EBPlatform-PlatformEngine
2022/09/29 17:05:39.149999 [INFO] reading event message file
2022/09/29 17:05:39.151835 [INFO] Engine received EB command cfn-hup-exec

2022/09/29 17:05:39.291599 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-2:882618350644:stack/awseb-e-2mwnvjecwe-stack/e6e0d050-3f75-11ed-a0e9-0a1f03d7e8a8 -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region eu-west-2
2022/09/29 17:05:40.014546 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-2:882618350644:stack/awseb-e-2mwnvjecwe-stack/e6e0d050-3f75-11ed-a0e9-0a1f03d7e8a8 -r AWSEBBeanstalkMetadata --region eu-west-2
2022/09/29 17:05:40.681829 [INFO] checking whether command tail-log is applicable to this instance...
2022/09/29 17:05:40.681845 [INFO] this command is applicable to the instance, thus instance should execute command
2022/09/29 17:05:40.681850 [INFO] Engine command: (tail-log)

2022/09/29 17:05:40.682976 [INFO] Executing instruction: GetTailLogs
2022/09/29 17:05:40.682984 [INFO] Tail Logs...
2022/09/29 17:05:40.685700 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c tail -n 100 /var/log/eb-hooks.log
2022/09/29 17:05:40.687855 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c tail -n 100 /var/log/nginx/access.log
2022/09/29 17:05:40.689449 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c tail -n 100 /var/log/nginx/error.log
2022/09/29 17:05:40.693994 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c tail -n 100 /var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/eb-48320d59a48b-stdouterr.log
2022/09/29 17:05:40.695588 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c tail -n 100 /var/log/docker-events.log
2022/09/29 17:05:40.702009 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c tail -n 100 /var/log/eb-docker-process.log
2022/09/29 17:05:40.703972 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c tail -n 100 /var/log/docker
2022/09/29 17:05:40.707914 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c tail -n 100 /var/log/eb-engine.log
```

The logs show that it is unable to delete the current docker images as the container is still running. I don't how I've caused that.

What is likely causing this?

Comment: The `/var/log/docker` log has error messages that mention the URL `unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock`. Does that URL come from your own code?